# Display an OverlayPanel on PrimeFaces 5.1

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I try to display an OverlayPanel, but for some reason is not displayed when the browser received the response.

### This is my source code:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="body">
        <h:form id="airForm">

        <p:dataTable value="#{dashboardManagedBean.dashboard}" var="dashboard"
            id="dashboardResult"
            style="width: 900px; margin-top: 10px; font-size: 16px;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                AIR Dashboard
            </f:facet>
            <p:columnGroup id="colGroup" type="header">
                <p:row>
                    <p:column colspan="3" style="font-size:14px;" headerText="" />
                    <p:column colspan="6" style="font-size:14px;"
                        headerText="Static Scan" />
                </p:row>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column headerText="Seal Id" style="font-size:12px" />
                    <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Name" style="font-size:12px" />
                    <p:column headerText="Phase" style="font-size:12px" />
                    <p:column headerText="Last Scan" style="font-size:12px" />
                    <p:column headerText="NVS" style="font-size:12px" />
                    <p:column headerText="Vulnerabilities" style="font-size:12px" />
                    <p:column headerText="ITRC" style="font-size:12px" />
                    <p:column headerText="Target Date" style="font-size:12px" />
                </p:row>
            </p:columnGroup>
            <p:column style="high:5px;font-size:10px;text-align:center;">
                <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.sealiD}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column colspan="2"
                style="high:5px;font-size:10px;text-align:center;">
                <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.name}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="high:5px;font-size:10px;text-align:center;">
                <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.onBoard}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="high:5px;font-size:10px;text-align:center;">
                <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.lastScan}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MMM-yy" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="high:5px;font-size:10px;text-align:center;">
                <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.nvs}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="high:5px;font-size:10px;text-align:center;">
                <p:commandLink id="numberOfVulnerabilities"
                    update=":airForm:vulnerabilityDetails"
                    oncomplete="PF('dashboardDialog').show('#{component.clientId}')">
                    <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.numberVulnerability}" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{dashboard}"
                        target="#{dashboardManagedBean.selectedDashboard}" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="high:5px;font-size:10px;text-align:center;">
                <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.issueTrackedItrc}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="high:5px;font-size:10px;text-align:center;">
                <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.targetDate}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MMM-yy" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:overlayPanel widgetVar="dashboardDialog" showEffect="fade"
            hideEffect="fade" dismissable="false" showCloseIcon="true">
            <p:outputPanel id="vulnerabilityDetails" style="text-align:center;">
                <p:panelGrid columns="1" rendered="true">
                    <p:chart type="pie"
                        model="#{dashboardManagedBean.selectedDashboard.vulnerabilities}"
                        style="width:400px;height:300px" />
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:overlayPanel>

    </h:form>


    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

---

The idea is display the OverlayPanel when the user press the command link 'numberOfVulnerabilities'

Could you help me to understand what is the problem please?

Comment: In this, `oncomplete="PF('dashboardDialog').show('#{component.clientId}')"`, what is the use of the specified parameter `'#{component.clientId}'` in the `show()` method?

Comment: I copy the example from http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/overlayPanel.xhtml , but I don't know the use of this parameter

Comment: Do you see some JavaScript errors on the browser console while trying to open this overlay panel (i.e. when you click the command link)?

Comment: I dont't have a javascript error. This is the content of the HTTP response:   <partial-response id="j_id1">
<changes>
<update id="airForm:vulnerabilityDetails"><div id="airForm:vulnerabilityDetails" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget" style="text-align:center;"><table id="airForm:j_idt38" class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget" role="grid"><tbody><tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">...........

Comment: I found the next Javascript error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Part of the Javascript code with the error is '.....splitExpressions:function(f){if(PrimeFaces.isIE(7)){f=f.split("")}var e=[];var b="";var a=0;for(var d=0;d<f.length;d++'

Comment: I have a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined' JavaScript error when I press the command link.

Comment: Try by removing the parameter to the `show()` method. I am not sure about the showcase example. I never had to pass any parameter to the `show()` method of this sort.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the show parameter (although I am not sure about the meaning, could be display position). This happens during the registering of widgetVar.  I am having the same problem. This seems to me a bug of primefaces